# Why can't you write the 2-paths problem as a max-flow problem?

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, network-flow

This is a follow-up question to [this](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/20989/graph-problems-which-are-np-complete-on-directed-graphs-but-polynomial-on-undire/20991#comment55620_20991). Consider the 2-paths problem:

> Given a directed graph $D=(V,A)$ and pairs of vertices $(s_1,t_1)$ and $(s_2,t_2)$, are there paths $P_1 = (s_1,\dots, t_1)$ and $P_2=(s_2,\dots,t_2)$ such that $P_1$ and $P_2$ are vertex-disjoint?

This problem has been shown to be NP-complete (references [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/20989/graph-problems-which-are-np-complete-on-directed-graphs-but-polynomial-on-undire/20991#comment55620_20991)). 
This struck me as unusual, because there seems to be a natural way to formulate this as a max flow problem:

- Add new vertices $s$ and $t$ to $D$.
- Add arcs $(s,s_1),(s,s_2),(t_1,t),(t_2,t)$.
- Let all vertices have capacity one (besides $s$ and $t$).

It seems to me that the max $s-t$ flow of this new graph (call it $D'$) should be two iff $D$ has those desired paths $P_1$ and $P_2$. Surely there must be some mistake here, because this seems to imply that an NP-complete problem can be solved in polytime. Where is the mistake?

Comment: How do you enforce the flow to only consist of two disjoint paths? Even with capacity 1 that doesn't mean the flow won't be split into a fractional amount.

Comment: @NicholasMancuso I don't think that is the issue. If there is a fractional flow of 2, there should be an integral flow of 2 (by total unimodularity). Anyways, Ford-Fulkerson finds an integral flow when the data is integral.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The proposed construction does find two vertex disjoint paths from s to t (if they exist). HOWEVER, the paths might be $P_1=(s_1,…,t_2)$ and $P_2=(s_2,…,t_1)$, which is not what we want.